# Unable to map sxatags_sm field to model

Tags: sxa, solr, indexing, sxa-search, index

I have indexed my content in the SOLR 8.8.2 and the tags available on those items are being pushed in the SOLR as below:

```json
{
    "description_t_en":"Lorem Ipsum is simply dum",
    "_templatename":"Insights Detail Page",
    "_creator":"",
    "sxatags_sm":["Gaming","Managed Services"],
    "_language":"en",
    "authored_date_tdt":"2022-05-21T00:00:00Z",
    "_uniqueid":"sitecore://master/{c8921b82-10c5..."
}
```

Now, due to some custom requirements, I want to map the Solr field sxatags_sm into my model as below:

```
[IndexField("sxatags_sm")]
  [DataMember]
  [TypeConverter(typeof(IndexFieldEnumerableConverter))]
  public virtual IEnumerable<string> TaggedIndustryAndServices { get; set; }
```

But I am not getting these values in my model. Any idea why is this so?

Comment: Please try without postfix "_sm". For ex. IndexField("sxatags").

Comment: No, it is still null.

Comment: I would also suggest removing the `TypeConverter` attribute as well as the `_sm` postfix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this in the custom Sitecore index config works for me!

```
<fieldNames hint="raw:AddFieldByFieldName">
    <field fieldName="sxatags" returnType="stringCollection"/> 
</fieldNames>
```

Comment: Is your index configured with `<IndexAllFields>false</IndexAllFields>`?

Comment: Yes, does this cause any issue?

Comment: No issue, but it explains why the field wasn’t added to the index by default.  This was the root of your problem.